# Query to find records following same sequence of patterns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How to find records which matches certain sequences from the below table:

```
ID  s_id    task
1   1       a
1   2       b
1   3       b
1   4       c
1   5       c
1   6       d
1   7       a
2   1       a
2   2       c
2   3       c
3   1       a
3   2       b
3   3       c
3   4       d
1   1       a
1   2       b
1   3       c
1   4       c
1   5       e
1   6       d
```

How to fetch the records following the below pattern

1. a
2. 1 or more b
3. c

Comment: This looks like a test question? Did you even make any try, of producing your own SQL?

Comment: More like home assignment.

Comment: Yes I tried.. But unable to proceed without knowing how to match certain sequence of records..

Comment: Can you also add what you've tried so far? What results did your attempts yield?

Comment: 2 points for creating a simplified scenario, but one of the columns is missing.

Comment: Vicky, are you familiar with the LEAD analytic function?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: Yes,Markovitz. I used that in below query, but its not getting recognized....       `select tasks, lead (tasks,1,0)
over (partition by id order by tasks) from tb_tasks;`                                             `Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'lead' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Vicky, it means that you are **not** using SQL Server 2012. `SELECT @@VERSION` will tell you the version.

Comment: Yes Baranov. Its                                                                          'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2))'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will transform your data to a list of site visits (id) followed by a single string of characters representing pages visited (e.g. "abbbcd").

```
       SELECT t2.id, max(tasks) as tasks from
        (
            SELECT t1.id, 
            (SELECT '' + Task FROM [Table] WHERE id = t1.id ORDER BY s_Id FOR XML PATH(''))  AS tasks
            from [Table] t1
        ) t2
        group by t2.id
```

So the problem is now reduced to searching for a pattern of characters: a--any number of b's--c. You can use LIKE to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT t2.id, max(tasks) as tasks from
        (
            SELECT t1.id, 
            (SELECT '' + Task FROM [Table] WHERE id = t1.id ORDER BY s_Id FOR XML PATH(''))  AS tasks
            from [Table] t1
        ) t2
        group by t2.id
    ) t3
WHERE t3.tasks LIKE '%abc%'
 OR t3.tasks LIKE '%abbc%'
  OR t3.tasks LIKE '%abbbc%' 
  OR t3.tasks LIKE '%abbbbc%';
```

This is a bit crude. You want to say any number of b's, but LIKE does not support that. This is what regular expressions (RegEx) is normally used for. The expression would be "ab+c" which stand for: "a" followed by 1 or more "b"s, followed by a "c".

Unfortunately, SQL server does not support regex (Oracle does), so you have to use CLR to implement it. Others have done this for you, so you can follow instructions here to install it: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

Comment: Should there be some `ORDER BY` around the `FOR XML` part to build the string in a defined order?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov well spotted, it does need ORDER BY clause. Corrected in the answer.